# varType usage in RODBC

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I am writing to from an ODBC to a SQL Server table via the `RODBC` package, specifically the function `sqlSave`.  It seems that the default var types is `charvar(255)` for this function.  I tried to use the argument of varTypes that is listed within the documentation but it fails.

Here is the table called `spikes20` with the Class structure, this in turn is what I am trying to save via sqlSave

```
sapply(spikes20, class)
Date       Day       EWW       PBR       BAC      CHTP        FB       SPY 
"Date"  "factor" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```

Here is the code which attempts to write to the SQL Server

```
require(RODBC)
varTypes = c(as.Date="Date") 
channel <-odbcConnect("OptionsAnalytics", uid="me", pwd="you")

sqlSave (channel, spikes20, tablename = NULL, append=TRUE, rownames = FALSE, colnames = TRUE, safer = FALSE, addPK = FALSE, varTypes=varTypes )
```

The error message that I get says:

Warning messages:

In sqlSave(channel, spikes20, tablename = NULL, append = TRUE, rownames = FALSE,  :
  column(s) as.Date 'dat' are not in the names of 'varTypes'

I tried to change the varType to:

```
varTypes=c(Date="Date")
```

then the **error message** becomes:

```
Error in sqlSave(channel, spikes20, tablename = NULL, append = TRUE, rownames = FALSE,  : 
  [RODBC] Failed exec in Update
22007 241 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Any help will be appreciated.  It seems I cannot decipher to use varTypes correctly...

Answer (score 8):

First, are you really trying to append to a table named NULL?

As far as issues with varTypes goes, in my experience I have had to provide a mapping for **all** of the variables in the data frame even though the documentation for the varTypes argurment says:

"an optional named character vector giving the DBMSs datatypes to be used for
**some** (or all) of the columns if a table is to be created"

You need to make sure that the names of your varTypes vector are the column names and the values are the data types as recommended [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/some-helpful-tips-on-using-RODBC-td2324503.html). So following their example you would have:

```
tmp <- sqlColumns(channel, correctTableName)
varTypes = as.character(tmp$TYPE_NAME)
names(varTypes) = as.character(tmp$COLUMN_NAME)
```

Comment: Thank you Pete, actually in the definition of the ODBC (from the control panel), I specified where to write to, hence the tablename being NULL is no issue.  I finally got varTypes to work on a subset of the columns.

Comment: The key was to put the varTypes within the sqlSave command as follow: sqlSave (channel, spikes20, tablename = NULL, append=TRUE, rownames = FALSE, colnames = FALSE, safer = FALSE, addPK = FALSE, varTypes=c(Date="Date"))

Answer (score 4):

varTypes = c(`somecolumn`="datetime") works for me.